# NetScaler and Domino iNotes

Tags: ibm-domino, netscaler

We are putting a NetScaler device in front of our Domino iNotes servers, which will act as a reverse proxy.

However, we get "Error 400" errors in the iNotes webinterface, and the behaviour is consistent with this documented issue: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21453878

How do we prevent NetScaler from stripping off the "X-IBM-INOTES-NONCE" header?

Answer (score 0):

[How to Load Balance the IBM Domino Webmail Servers](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX129115) does not help?